# Analyse de « en », pronom (« La porte en donnait sur la cour. », La Peste, Albert Camus)

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, en

> C’était aussi l’avis des autres, mais ils
> restaient quand même, malgré la chaleur meurtrière.
> Rambert montra son laissez-passer au sergent qui lui
> indiqua le bureau de Tarrou. La porte en donnait sur la
> cour. Il croisa le père Paneloux, qui sortait du bureau.

Comment analyser ce pronom ? Il n'est ni cod ni coi. On s'attend simplement à « La porte donnait sur la cour. ». On a l'impression que l'auteur fait du pronom un complément de nom, une notion qu'on ne trouve nulle part (« la porte du bureau »). À moins qu'il ne s'agisse d'une  construction très rare (ce que je ne crois pas), il y aurait une erreur.

Comment: Bizarre de suggérer la possibilité d'une _erreur_ dans un texte d'un prix Nobel de littérature... Un auteur tel que Camus serait plutôt une _référence_, qui fournira des exemples à TLFi, LBU et bien d'autres.

Comment: Il existe bien une collection des erreurs faites par Victor Hugo et d'autres aussi célèbres que lui. Je ne présume de rien dans ce domaine, et, franchement, cette construction grince dans mes oreilles. D'après ce que j'ai lu elle carrément interdite lorsque le verbe a un complément d'objet (« Le soleil se lève ; les rayons en percent les nuages à l'horizon. »). Il n'y a pas loin de cette construction à celle du texte de La Peste.

Answer (score 6):

Cet *en* est bien *le bureau de Tarrou*. Aucune erreur. C'est une construction assez courante. On peut dire par exemple:

> *il avait une maison. Le toit en était pourri*.

> *Il avait lu un livre. La lecture en avait été difficile*.

Comment: *Dans le jardin , en suivant cette issue , Est un pavillon isolé ; La porte en donne sur la rue ...* Scribe

Comment: Quels sont les principes de grammaire auxquels vous faites référence ? Je viens de faire un peu plus de recherche et j'ai découvert ceci dans l'article 609 (c 2°) du LBU : « Le nom déterminé est sujet, le possessif prédomine, même si
l'antécédent est non humain.». Ce serait donc assez rare.

Comment: @LPH je confirme que c'est un usage courant. Voir https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/en EN(2) _Ma mère était à moi, personne ne m'en contestait la tranquille possession (Sartre, Mots,1964, p. 17)_

Answer (score 2):

Le pronom remplace le [complément du nom](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/23513/la-grammaire/les-pronoms/pronoms-personnels/le-pronom-personnel-en) *porte* (la *porte du bureau*), c'est-à-dire *bureau* . La prédominance du possessif peut être renversée par le désir d'éviter l'équivoque d'un référent possible à l'animé :

> Ce qui l'accablait encore plus que la souffrance du monde, C'EN était
> l'imbécillité (R ROLLAND, *Pierre et Luce*, p. 24) (LBU14, 609 c 2°)

Mais entre la *porte de Tarrou* et *la porte du bureau de Tarrou*, il n'y a qu'un pas, de métonymie... sauf qu'on semble aimer l'ordre grammatical. Reste que *prédominance* ne signifie pas *exclusivité* et je trouve *la porte donnait sur la cour* imprécis.

Comment: En l'absence d'ambiguité sur "l'appartenance" de la porte, j'aurais préféré "*Sa porte donnait sur la cour*".